# When creating a Twitter account, how to skip "Follow people to get their Tweets"

Tags: twitter

When creating a Twitter account, I am asked to follow 5 accounts:

> Build your timeline. Follow people to get their Tweets

And then 5 again:

> See who’s here. Find and follow well-known people

I don't intend to follow anybody. How to skip these steps?

[image]

Comment: There usually is a Skip link or button hidden at the lower right

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: In the subsequent steps there is a Skip button, but not in the first step.

Comment: @pnuts: That's what I ended up doing. Feel free to propose this as an answer, as there does not seem to be anything better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to do all that stuff, you can manually go to the [Twitter homepage](https://twitter.com) right after signing up and you end up on your empty new timeline, and then feel free to do whatever you want without being forced to follow obnoxious celebrity accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the minimum and then unfollow them soon after the sign-up process is complete.

Since anyone signing up for Twitter may

1. be expected to want to try their services but
2. not be familiar with them

enforcing a small sample selection during the (guided) sign up process seems quite reasonable to me.

Then, once the installation process is compete the user can immediately proceed with testing the system out without being left to struggle independently, in what may be unfamiliar software, finding how to follow people.

So there is some reason to expect that bypassing these requirements, if even possible, may not be straightforward.

Comment: As a non US citizen or American, who knows